# How does negative margin on first child affect the position of the next elements?

Tags: html, css

if I have this dom structure

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="d1" style="margin-top:-50px; height:10px;"></div>
    <div id="d2" style="height:30px;"></div>
    <div id="d3" style="height:30px;"></div>
</div>
```

My question is how the elements d2 and d3 will be placed? just after the first element? even if d2 will be hidden, and d3 will be half-hidden (10px hidden). Or the two elements will be placed in the visible area of the parent?

My question here is about the exact CSS specifications.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out in a code editor like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Probably because jsfiddle.net doesn't quote the CSS specs in context (unless that's a new feature I'm not aware of)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does negative margin on first child affect the position of the next elements?

No differently than how a zero or positive margin affects the position of the following elements, assuming everything is in the flow: a positive margin from the top pushes a box and following boxes downward, so it follows that a negative margin from the top pulls a box and following boxes upward. The value of the `overflow` property on the containing block is irrelevant in normal flow.

The spec does not mention this explicitly, simply because there are no special rules around negative margins in this specific scenario. It's just basic math. There are numerous other special rules around negative margins, but none of them apply in this scenario at all.

Answer (score 1):

> How does negative margin on first child affect the position of the
>   next elements?

Simply put, they follow, though it is a little more complicated than that, so I recommend read more here for the specifications.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin
- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
#d {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
#d1 {
  background: green;
}
#d2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#d3 {
  background: blue;
}

/*  these is for demo purpose only  */
#d:before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#d:after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
    <div id="d1" style="margin-top:-50px; height:10px;"></div>
    <div id="d2" style="height:30px;"></div>
    <div id="d3" style="height:30px;"></div>
</div>
```